# How many roots can $P(x):=\sum_s(x-s)^{(p-1)/2}$ have in ${\mathbb F}_p$?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

For a prime $p$ and a set $S\subset{\mathbb F}_p$ of size $n:=|S|\approx \sqrt p$, what is the largest possible number of roots that the polynomial 
                $$  P(x) := \sum_{s\in S} (x-s)^{\frac{p-1}2}  $$
can have? What is the smallest possible number of values that this polynomial can attain?

Trivially, there are at most $\frac{p-1}2$ roots and at least three values. Are these estimates ever attained?

If $n=1$, there is just one root and three values attained. If $n=2$, there are $\frac{p-1}2$ (pairwise distinct) roots. However, this is unlikely to have anything to do with the situation where $n\approx\sqrt p$.

Comment: The estimates are attained: Take $p = 3$, $n = 1$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jmc: The question is about $n$ and $p$ both growing, with $n\approx\sqrt p$.

Comment: So you mean whether the estimates are attained for arbitrarily large $p$? That was not clear to me, sorry.

Comment: It looks like P is the convolution of $1_S$ with the quadratic character; it reminds me of various difficult unsolved conjectures about the Paley graph, and so one might not be able to say very much here other than what one can get from standard Fourier-analytic methods.

Comment: @Terry: absolutely - this *is* a convolution, and the question is motivated by Paley graph - related busyness; but, maybe, this is the right approach to a difficult problem? Even showing that $P(x)$ cannot have $\frac{p-1}2$ distinct roots, or that it cannot attain just three distinct values, would yield an (admittedly, tiny) improvement in the current bound on the clique size in the Paley graph.